# java.lang.NullPointerException ( nutch 2.2.1 and MySql as datastore)

Tags: java, mysql, nutch

I  am new in this area. 
I started with this tutorial:http://nlp.solutions.asia/?p=362#more-362. WHen i first crawled this url: nutch.apache.org, i had sucess, but when i tried a different url, i had this exception in my hadoop.log.

```
**java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.avro.util.Utf8.<init>(Utf8.java:37)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorReducer.setup(GeneratorReducer.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:649)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:398)**
```

---

this is my nutch-site.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
<property>
<name>http.agent.name</name>
<value>Maria</value>
</property>

<property> 
<name>http.robots.agents</name> 
<value>Maria</value> ....
</description> 
</property>

<property>
<name>http.accept.language</name>
<value>ja-jp, en-us,en-gb,en;q=0.7,*;q=0.3</value>
<description>Value of the “Accept-Language” request header field.
This allows selecting non-English language as default one to retrieve.
It is a useful setting for search engines build for certain national group.
</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>parser.character.encoding.default</name>
<value>utf-8</value>
<description>The character encoding to fall back to when no other information
is available</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>storage.data.store.class</name>
<value>org.apache.gora.sql.store.SqlStore</value>
<description>The Gora DataStore class for storing and retrieving data.
Currently the following stores are available: ….
</description>
</property>

</configuration>
```

---

And this is the regex-ulrfilter.txt:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.


# The default url filter.
# Better for whole-internet crawling.

# Each non-comment, non-blank line contains a regular expression
# prefixed by '+' or '-'.  The first matching pattern in the file
# determines whether a URL is included or ignored.  If no pattern
# matches, the URL is ignored.

# skip file: ftp: and mailto: urls
-^(file|ftp|mailto):

# skip image and other suffixes we can't yet parse
# for a more extensive coverage use the urlfilter-suffix plugin
-\.          
(gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|png|PNG|ico|ICO|css|CSS|sit|SIT|eps|EPS|wmf|WMF|zip
|ZIP|ppt|PPT|mpg|MPG|xls|XLS|gz|GZ|rpm|RPM|tgz|TGZ|mov
|MOV|exe|EXE|jpeg|JPEG|bmp|BMP|js|JS)$

# skip URLs containing certain characters as probable queries, etc.
-[?*!@=]

# skip URLs with slash-delimited segment that repeats 3+ times, to break loops
-.*(/[^/]+)/[^/]+\1/[^/]+\1/

# accept anything else
#+.

+^http://([a-z0-9]*\.)* nutch.apache.org/

#
-.
```

---

I would appreciate any suggestion to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I have never used nutch, but it seems a common error, a NPE launched at init means the UTF8 instance failed at creation.

the reason is that the 'crawl' function is deprecated in Nutch2 in favor of a java file located in 'bin/crawl'

just copy the file $NUTCH_HOME/src/bin/crawl to the deploy directory: $NUTCH_HOME/runtime/deploy/bin and then run the crawl commands, take a look here :

http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial#A3.1_Using_the_Crawl_Command

Hope this helps.